# Turning off a site in multi-site/multi-environment config

Tags: craft3, config, configuration

Given a multi site setup (domain1.com, domain2.com) that also uses multiple environments (dev, staging, production) - how would one configure one of the sites to be turned off in the production environment?

I'm currently trying the following.

```
return [
    // Global settings
    '*' => [
        // removed for clarity
    ],


    'dev' => [
        'devMode' => true,
        'isSystemLive' => [
            'domain1.com' => true,
            'domain2.com' => false
        ]
    ],

    // Staging environment settings
    'staging' => [
        'devMode' => true,
        'isSystemLive' => [
            'domain1.com' => true,
            'domain2.com' => false
        ]
    ],

    // Production environment settings
    'production' => [
        'devMode' => false,
        'isSystemLive' => [
            'domain1.com' => true,
            'domain2.com' => false
        ]
    ]
];
```

Which I would have expected to have domain2.com turned off but domain1.com remains on. However, both sites are on.

I have also tried rearranging the config using the following structure (stripped back for brevity)

```
return [
    'domain1.com' => [
        '*' => [
            // default for domain1
        ],

        'dev' => [
            'isSystemLive' => true
        ],

        'staging' => [
            'isSystemLive' => true
        ],

        'production' => [
            'isSystemLive' => true
        ]
    ],

    'domain2.com' => [
        '*' => [
            // default for domain2
        ],

        'dev' => [
            'isSystemLive' => false
        ],

        'staging' => [
            'isSystemLive' => false
        ],

        'production' => [
            'isSystemLive' => false
        ]
    ],
]
```

But this also doesn't work.

So how should I specify different multi-environment configs for each site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `isSystemLive` config setting isn't multi-site aware. It sets the entire Craft installation on or off, rather than per site, so you'll need to find a different method to disable `domain2.com` on the production server.

Untested, but you could try to set the `baseUrl` for `domain2.com` to an empty string on production and see if that works.

Comment: Just discovered this while submitting a Feature request. https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/3005  Thanks!

Comment: For the record, I turned off "This site has a base url" and set the site url to a blank string as suggested. Not sure

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Apache, you could set your `ENVIRONMENT` variable in your `<VirtualHost>` directive using `SetEnv ENVIRONMENT "domain2"` then have a section:

```php
'domain2' => [
   'isSystemLive' => false
],
```

In your `config/general.php`.